# How can I print an entire string cell of a tibble?

Tags: r, string, tibble, stringi

I have a tibble that contains long strings in it's cells.

How can I view the complete string in a cell, without tibble restricting the number of characters I see?

Let's say I have my tibble created like this:

```
library(stringi)
df <- tibble(example = stri_paste(rep(stri_paste(letters, collapse = " "), 4), collapse = " "))
```

Then when I want to view a cell with `df[1, 1]` the output looks like:

```
# A tibble: 1 x 1
  example                                                                                 
  <chr>                                                                                   
1 a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r…
```

But I want to read the entire string in the cell.

How do I do this? Thanks ahead!

Comment: convert it to dataframe? `data.frame(df)` ?

Comment: Do you need `df[[1, 1]]` ?

Comment: @RonakShah, I would like to stick to the tidyverse approach, so that's why I chose tibble.

Comment: @markus, Thanks! That is the solution! Do you happen to know why this double indexing does the trick?

Comment: If you want a `tidyverse` solution, you could use `pull` to get a character vector,  `df %>% pull(example)`

Comment: @JNab Check the link Ronak posted. The double brackets extracts a vector, while the single bracket returns a `tibble`. Note that this behavior is different compared to regular `data.frame`s. Look at the default of the `drop` argument in `?"[.tbl_df"` compared to `?"[.data.frame"`.